# use spark-streaming to execute sql and write DataFrame to HDFS in spark as a table rather than lots of empty or small files

Tags: hdfs, spark-streaming

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
  val sparkConf = new   SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("kafka-spark-demo")
  val scc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Duration(5000))
  val topics = Set("test1")
  val kafkaParam = Map(
  "metadata.broker.list" -> "localhost:9092"
)

  val stream: InputDStream[(String, String)] = createStream(scc, kafkaParam, topics)

  val words = stream.map(_._2)
  .flatMap(_.split(" "))

  // Convert RDDs of the words DStream to DataFrame and run SQL query
  words.foreachRDD { (rdd: RDD[String], time: Time) =>
  // Get the singleton instance of SparkSession
  val spark = SparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext.getConf)
  import spark.implicits._

  // Convert RDD[String] to RDD[case class] to DataFrame
  val wordsDataFrame = rdd.map(w => Record(w)).toDF()

  // Creates a temporary view using the DataFrame
  wordsDataFrame.createOrReplaceTempView("words")

  // Do word count on table using SQL and print it
  val wordCountsDataFrame =
    spark.sql("select word, count(*) as total from words group by word")
  wordCountsDataFrame.show()   wordCountsDataFrame.rdd.saveAsTextFile(dir)
}
  scc.start()
  scc.awaitTermination()
```

}

This is my code about use spark-streaming to execute sql messages and save the result into HDFS,but I found I output lots of empty or small files(only have one line data) rather than a table.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this and let me know if it helps.

`wordCountsDataFrame.rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output")`

Comment: I finally try this: wordCountsDataFrame.rdd.coalesce(1,false).saveAsTextFile("/path/to/output")   I know the result that there are too many patitions that write messages in hdfs.